# Change image on hover in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, onmouseover, onmouseout

How do I change an image on `hover` in JSX

I'm trying something like this:

```
<img src={require('../../../common/assets/network-inactive.png')}
onMouseOver={this.src = require('../../../common/assets/network.png')}
onMouseOut={this.src = require('../../../common/assets/network-inactive.png')} />
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I will assume you are writing this code in a React component. Such as:

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <img src={require('../../../common/assets/network-inactive.png')}
       onMouseOver={this.src = require('../../../common/assets/network.png')}
       onMouseOut={this.src = require('../../../common/assets/network-inactive.png')} 
       />
    );
  }
}
```

Targeting `this.src` will not work in this case as you are essentially looking for something named `src` in your class. For instance `this.src` could find something like this:

```
src = () => (alert("a source"))
```

But that is not what you want to do. You want to target the image itself.

Therfore you need to enter the `<img />` context. You can do that easily like this:

```
 <img
    onMouseOver={e => console.log(e)}
  />
```

From there you can target the `currentTarget` property, among others. This will enter the context of your element. So now you can do something like this:

```
  <img
    src="img1"
    onMouseOver={e => (e.currentTarget.src = "img2")}
  />
```

The same can be done for `onMouseOut`.

You can use this same method on your other elements, as you will certainly need to do this again. But be careful as this is a not the only solution. On bigger projects you may want to consider using a store ([Redux](https://redux.js.org/)), and passing props rather than mutating elements.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I realized later. I rather went with the CSS way to tackle the problem. Yes I am using redux in the project and I will implement your suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome @new-boy-in-web-dev-business :) I'm happy for you.

Comment: @TypeKev  So in which case `this.src` will work ? Looking for your comment forward.

Comment: @hardy, sorry I just saw your reply now. I'm a bit late, but in this case, to accomplish the mutation of props within the img context, you would need to write a function called src that basically does what @ new-boy-in-web-dev-business is doing inline. 

i.e have a function named `src` whithin your class:


`src = ({ currentTarget: { src } }) => src = "img2"`.


This will accomplish the same thing - set the src of currentTarget (which is the `img` element) to 'img2' :)

Answer (score 13):

Best is to manage this in the state:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    img: "https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <img
          src={this.state.img}
          onMouseEnter={() => {
            this.setState({
              img: "http://www.toptipsclub.com/Images/page-img/keep-calm-and-prepare-for-a-test.png"
            })
          }}

          onMouseOut={() => {
            this.setState({
              img: "https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300"
            })
          }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/5437qm907l

Comment: Mine is a stateless component (Functional Component).

Answer (score 5):

Another non-class approach:

```
import arrow from "../images/arrow.svg";
import arrowHover from "../images/arrowHover.svg";

function Arrow() {
  const [over, setOver] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div
      onMouseOver={() => setOver(true)}
      onMouseOut={() => setOver(false)}
    >
         <img
          src={over ? arrowHover : arrow}
          alt="arrow"
          width="50"
          height="50"
        />
    </div>   
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-class approach using a functional component and typescript:

```
interface IconProps {
  src?: string;
  srcOnHover?: string;
  alt?: string;
}

const Icon: React.FC<IconProps> = ({ src, srcOnHover, alt }) => (
  <img
    src={src}
    alt={alt}
    onMouseOver={(e): void => {
      srcOnHover && (e.currentTarget.src = srcOnHover);
    }}
    onMouseOut={(e): void => {
      srcOnHover && (e.currentTarget.src = src || '');
    }}
  />
);
```

It can be used like that:

```
<Icon src="path/to/image.png" srcOnHover="path/to/hover-image.png" alt="Description" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good one for handling image src in React with onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave. Contributing this non class based component version.

```js
   import React, { useState } from 'react';
   
   function imageHoveControl({) {
     let imageVar = {
       nonhovered: '/public/image.jpg'
       hovered: '/public/imageHover.jpg'
     }
        let selectorDown = imageVar.nonhovered.src
        let selectorUp = imageVar.hovered.src
        //Pop "up" to meet cursor on hover 
        const [selectorImage, setSelectorImage] = useState(selectorDown);

        function handleMouseEnter() {
          setSelectorImage(selectorUp)
        }
        function handleMouseLeave() {
          setSelectorImage(selectorDown)
        }

          return (
              <img
                className="rounded-full h-14 w-14 sm:h-20 sm:w-20 bg-contain mx-1"
                src={selectorImage}
                onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
                onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
              />
          )
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

**simple way to do this:**

class Home extends React.Component {
state = {
icon: ICON_ONE
}

render(){
return(
<img
src={this.state.icon}
onMouseOver={()=>this.setState({icon:ICON_TWO})}
onMouseOut={() => this.setState({ icon: ICON_ONE })}
/>
)
}